# Should I ground a sensor locally or at the microcontroller input?

Tags: sensor, ground, ground-loop

If I had a sensor with an analog voltage output (temperature or pressure with slow sampling rate) and a common chassis ground available (like a boat, plane, or car), should I ground it locally or at the microcontroller? Would it also make a difference if the sensor power was provided locally or also at the microcontroller input?

I drew diagrams A, B, C, and D. I think B or C would be better to have a twisted pair (or triple), to avoid the single signal wire in A picking up any noise, and to have a star ground at the microcontroller.

I would assume diagram A or D is a bad implementation then, but at least it would save some wire runs.

Thanks!

[image: Sensor diagram A, B, C, D]

Comment: If you had a sensor, the answer would depend what sensor it is, what does it output and how to wire it. There is a great differene if the ouput has slow bandwidth like temperature measurement or if it is a camera image sensor requiring 20 GHz of bandwidth.

Comment: Good point, just updated the description. It's a "slow" sensor like temperature or pressure.

Answer (score 0):

The "ground" terminal should be referenced to the sensor's power source, which I assume to be the analogue or digital supply of the microcontroller. Do not use the chassis ground for that purpose, you are likely to introduce errors (as the voltage at two points of the chassis will be different under some condition).

I don't think a twisted pair will help much as the signal is not differential. A twisted triple will help slightly. A shielded cable with a shield that is connected at one end to "ground" would be effective at stopping radiated noise.

Of the options presented, C looks the best.

Comment: Why do you think twisted pair won't help? What difference would it make to a twisted pair if the signal is differential or not?

Comment: I will refer to a past question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/290310/does-using-twisted-pair-wiring-make-sense-only-for-differential-signalling

Comment: The answers there indicate it is useful for single ended signals as well. Also in a system where you have a signal wire for signal currents and a ground wire as a return path for the signal currents, isn't that basically differential anyway? Twisting will reduce loop area and if there is induced noise in one loop it gets almost cancelled in the next loop.

Comment: One problem comes from power supply to the sensor itself. If it draws a spike of current, and only the "ground" (negative supply) and signal wires are twisted, inductive voltage drop from the "ground" wire appears in opposite polarity on the signal wire, thus doubled at the microcontroller input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like any of those options.  You're sending a single-ended an analog signal 20ft, use a coaxial cable. They're cheap, controlled impedance and have great noise immunity. Run a separate cable for the +5V and power supply ground, or plug it in locally.

Second, I don't see any reason you necessarily need to connect to chassis ground.  There are no safety issues with 5V, and chassis ground doesn't matter here since your sensor is not actually inside the chassis.  I would leave the MCU grounded however its own power supply connects it.

Comment: Depending on the signal in question, maybe even use triaxial cable. But that would be some very special-purpose stuff.

Comment: Just added more sensor details - it'd be for a temperature or pressure sensor with low bandwidth. I've never seen an implementation using coax that wasn't RF or an accelerometer, but will consider thanks.

If I had many sensors then there would be a lot of ground/return wiring.. Perhaps I should add local data concentrators that then feed over a comms bus to the controller then.

Comment: @James If you look at commercial DAQ hardware (NI, etc) they'll typically have coaxial connections, even at KHz bandwidths because the shield all around gives good noise rejection for single ended signals and it is quite cheap (10s of cents per foot).   In this case the controlled impedance is irrelevant, but it doesn't hurt.